# Multi Step form in lightbox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this multi stage form i want to embed this form in a light box i have no clue how to do it i have searched a lot but couldn't find anything please guide me.

i have used jquery and css to achieve this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})


});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
  url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- multistep form -->
<body>
<form id="msform">
 <!-- progressbar -->
 <ul id="progressbar">
  <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
  <li>Social Profiles</li>
  <li>Personal Details</li>
 </ul>
 <!-- fieldsets -->
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
  <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
  <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
  <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
  <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `<form id="msform">` inside an `<div>` and to that give the properties and use jquery onlcik event to show and hide your form such as :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#show_form').on('click',function(){
      $('.stepsForm').show();
});
    $('#hide_form').on('click',function(){
      $('.stepsForm').hide();
});

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})


});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
  url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
.action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
.stepsForm {
display:none;
position:fixed;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index:99;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.stepsForm{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- multistep form -->
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_form" class="action-button">Show Form</a>
<div class="stepsForm">
 <div class="modal">
<form id="msform">
 <!-- progressbar -->
 <ul id="progressbar">
  <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
  <li>Social Profiles</li>
  <li>Personal Details</li>
 </ul>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="hide_form" class="action-button">Hide Form</a>
 <!-- fieldsets -->
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
  <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
  <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
  <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
  <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```